# Changing my user-name

Tags: support, user-interface, display-names

I would like to request a change to my user-name. I would prefer to have something more colorful than my user number How do I submit such  a request"?

Comment: Side note:  you [cannot change the user name too often within a given time frame](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38289/why-can-i-only-change-my-stack-overflow-name-once-every-30-days). That is to say, do not take something too colorful that you might come to regret after a few days.

Comment: Once will be enough for me. I use DanielWainfleet elsewhere already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to your [Profile page](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current) (on the main site, it doesn't work on Meta), change your Display Name and scroll down. You'll find two Save buttons; one to apply this change for this site only, and to apply it to all sites on the Stack Exchange network.

[image]

---

[image]