# How to change user name?

Tags: support, display-names

Is there anyone who can help me on how to change my user name? Was looking for it already but couldn't find it. Cheers!

Comment: In your user page you find a tab [Edit profile & settings](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/edit/389367). There you can edit your display name, location information, as well as the "about me" box.

Comment: Note that you cannot change it frequently though. (Only once a month, roughly.) Thus, use your ability wisely.

Comment: See also: [Changing my user-name](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26249)